# Issue loading PostGIS out-db rasters (either in QGIS or MapServer)

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, mapserver

I'm playing with a few different options of storing raster data via PostGIS to visualize (eventually in a web app).

The out-db or out-of-database storage seems the best option, but I can't seem to get it to work outside of PostGIS. Functions within PostGIS (like `ST_Histogram`) output fine results, but taking it outside fails.

First I tried MapServer since that's how I eventually want to handle it.

```
LAYER
    NAME test
    TYPE raster
    STATUS ON
    DATA "PG:host=website.com port=1234 
          dbname='raster_dev' user='username' password='password' 
          schema='public' table='rasters_outdb' where='\'rid\'=1'"
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:3310"
    END
    PROCESSING "NODATA=252"
    PROCESSING "RESAMPLE=NEAREST"
END
```

Results in this error:

```
msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'test'. drawGDAL(): Unable to access file. GDALDatasetRasterIO() failed: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0
```

If I change `table` to `rasters_indb` (the in-db storage option), the map/png loads fine.

So I tried loading it up in QGIS. Again, in-db works fine. Out-db, I get a blank, black raster, with nan for min/max values -- however it does seem to occupy the right location and size. Progress?

I did a lot of googling and I seem to get mixed results on whether it works, whether GDAL can handle out-db or not, and most of it outdated. So I'm not sure where I stand here. Am I trying something that just isn't supported yet or am I doing something above wrong?

I'm on QGIS 2.12, MapServer 7, PostgreSQL 9.4, PostGIS 2.1

Answer (score 1):

I have had success reading vectors from Postgis.  I haven't tried Raster access, but maybe some of this will help?  For starters, check out [PostGIS Support in MapServer](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/PostGIS)

I dont have access to your database/schema and I've never stored a raster in Postgis... but you could try something like this:

```
LAYER
    NAME test
    TYPE raster
    STATUS ON
    CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
    CONNECTION "host=website.com port=1234 user=username dbname=raster_dev password=password"

    # Turn on Mapserver Connection pool for performance
    # http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2008/10/mapserverpostgis-performance-tips.html
    PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"

    DATA "SELECT table.rgb_bytes FROM table WHERE table.id=1 and  ST_Intersects(table.geom, !BOX!)"
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:3310"
    END
    PROCESSING "NODATA=252"
    PROCESSING "RESAMPLE=NEAREST"
END
```

If your Postgis database acts as a tileindex, create a LAYER with `TYPE vector` and your query in `DATA` includes `location`, the path to the image on disk.

```
LAYER
    NAME tindex_layer
    TYPE vector
    STATUS OFF
    CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
    CONNECTION "host=website.com port=1234 user=username dbname=raster_dev password=password"
    PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"

    DATA "geom FROM (SELECT geom,id,location FROM table WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, !BOX!) AS subquery USING UNIQUE id USING SRID=4326
END
```

Then you make another raster layer with the tileindex, like so:

```
LAYER
    NAME raster_layer
    TYPE raster
    STATUS ON
    TILEINDEX tindex_layer
END
```